# How to build a programmable website?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm developing pretty normal, non-brilliant Web 2.0 applications, like blogs, forums, social networks, etc.

APIs, mashups, greasemonkey-like works are okay for developers. But for end-users, my websites can't provide something more than a-gazillion-paper magazine. I want my users to create their own program logic to create information, access to data and communicate each other based on their own way.

The most advanced programmability on the websites are all about "Show 20 results per page", moving GUI elements around or changing colors of design.

Is there a study or do you have an idea to make websites allow their users to manipulate/create application logic, data structure, access methods both in client-side and server-side easily?

Thanks!

*Please accept my apologizes for poor English, I'm not a native speaker.*

Comment: I remember that ebay had big security issues because the allowed users to embed JavaScript in their offers. Hence, you need to put a lot of thoughts into security when you want to provide your users with scripting capabilities.

Comment: There's also [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/). It was hyped back when 'mashup' was a buzz word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. Long answer, not yet but this is probably a long term goal of web development overall. There are some "build your own web apps" web apps around but none of them go much beyond your simple description.

The most useful thing I have come across is something called pyjsglade:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyjsglade/

Which lets someone build a web gui in an IDE which then automagically turns into a webpage with full AJAX capabilities. It doesn't do everything you want but it's worth a look certainly.